# XCode TextField Hide Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In my application I am having different `TextFields` like `Username`, `Name`, `Password` etc.

in that I am using the following `textfields` Age, Gender and Country as `ActionSheet` pickers. The problem I am facing is when I type `password` field and move to select age, the keyboard is not hiding in the first click itself. I have to click the age field again after that keyboard hides.

Can any one help me to solve this issue

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(LRTextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"Tag %ld",(long)textField.tag);
  if (textField.tag == 3){
    return NO;
  } else if (textField.tag == 4){
    return NO;
  } else if (textField.tag==5){
    return NO;
  } else if (textField.tag==6){
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

I am using `LTTextField` for `textfield` validations.

Comment: Alternative solution: instead of textfields Age, Gender and Country, use UIButtons.

Comment: Where is the `resignFirstResponder:` ? `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` if returning `NO` then this will prevent the editing but it will not resign that `textField` which is already focused.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below step

Make one simple button on that pickerview textfield

Add action

```
- (IBAction)hidekey:(id)sender {


    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [_yourpickerview setHidden:NO];

}
```

here all textfield `resignFirstResponder`

So when ever you move on  that `textfield` keyboard will hide and pickerview show

Hope work for you

Comment: Thanks I had solved this issue when this action is called - (IBAction)selectAge:(UIControl *)sender { here put end editing code} this has solved my problem. I guess this is the best way to solve this issue

Comment: no need to write each textfield resignFirstresponser @RushangPrajapati. Just need one line of code on that IBAction method.

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES]; It just notify end editing of all textfields and hide keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resignFirstResponder`:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField.tag = passwordTag {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()        
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I made this little piece of code which move at the right position for each IPhone.
In your viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

And just after:

```
 - (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif{
        CGSize keyboardsize = [[[notif userInfo]objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]CGRectValue].size;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        long moveScreen = ((long)(keyboardsize.height) - (long)(self.view.frame.size.height) + 465) * -1;
        if (moveScreen > 0)
            moveScreen = 0;
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,moveScreen,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    - (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notif{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        self.view.frame = rect;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

                if textField == self.emailField {
                  self.usernameField.becomeFirstResponder()
                } 
                else if textField == self.usernameField {
                  self.nameField.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                else if textField == self.nameField {
                  self.passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
                }

                else if textField == self.passwordField {
                  self.ageField.becomeFirstResponder()
                  self.ageField.resignFirstResponder();
                }

                return true;
              }
```

make ageTextField the first responder then resign the first responder